# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "9231054287"

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de ingresar un numero de teléfono en un formulario pero al momento de ingresarlo me suelta el error del titulo, ya hice algunas pruebas y si acepta hasta 9 digitos, pense que era que solo aceptaba 9 digitos pero tambien ya intente ingresar los digitos "1234567890" y si los acepta, no se que es lo que sucede, dejo el codigo.

```
Iglesia oIglesia = new Iglesia();
    String nombreIglesia = "";
    int distrito = 0;
    int telefono = 0;
    int codigoPostal = 0;

    float salarioPastor = 0;
    String domicilio = "";
    String colonia = "";

    nombreIglesia = txtNombreIglesia.getText();
    try{
        distrito = Integer.parseInt(cbxDistrito.getSelectedItem().toString());

        telefono = Integer.parseInt(txtTelefono.getText());
        codigoPostal = Integer.parseInt(txtCodigoPostal.getText());
        salarioPastor = Float.parseFloat(txtSalarioPastor.getText());
    }catch(NullPointerException error){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Tipo de dato incorrecto, ingrese solo numeros", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

    domicilio = txtDomicilio.getText();
    colonia = txtColonia.getText();


    System.out.println(telefono);
    String salida = "-------INFORMACIÓN A REGISTRAR-------\n";
    salida += "Nombre del producto: " + nombreIglesia + "\n";
    salida += "Distrito: " +distrito + "\n";
    salida += "Teléfono: " +telefono + "\n";
    salida += "Salario del Pastor: " +salarioPastor + "\n";
    salida += "Domicilio de la Iglesia: " + domicilio + "\n";
    salida += "Colonia: " + colonia + "\n";
    salida += "Codigo Postal: " + codigoPostal + "\n";
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, salida);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema son los límites, `int` soporta hasta **32** bits. Para almacenar *9231054287* se requieren más de 32 bits, intenta convertirlo a binario. Te dejo esta [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2) de oracle para revisar los límites de varios tipos de datos.

El máximo valor positivo que puede almacenar un `int` es *2 147 483 647*, que evidentemente es mucho menor que el que quieres almacenar *9 231 054 287*. Todo valor positivo que sea almacenado en un `int` debe de ser menor o igual a *2 147 483 647*.

Te dejo un pequeño código para que revises esto.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Integer positive limit: " + Integer.MAX_VALUE); // 2 147 483 647
        System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE >= 9231054287L); // false
        System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE >= 1234567890); // true
    }
}
```

De hecho, como puedes observar, a tu número *9 231 054 287* le tuve que agregar una *L* al final, porque como lo mencioné, ese valor no se puede guardar en un `int` tiene que almacenarse en más bits, y `long` tiene capacidad de hasta 64 bits, por ello ese número tiene la *L* (de *Long*). Prueba quitarle la L a ver qué sucede.

En fin, la solución a ello sería utilizar en vez de `int`, `long`.

Aunque recomendaría no usar ninguno de los dos pues un número se puede escribir de muchas formas, e.g. `+55 1 123 546 987` o `(014) 666 777 888`, así que hay que tener cuidado con ese tipo de detalles que harían que `Integer.parseInt` no lograra parsear bien el número.